# Can a UIView "ignore" interface orientation?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, augmented-reality, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a `UIView` associated with it's own `UIViewController` that I want to always be locked to portrait mode.

Imagine that it wants to act like a window into the internals of the iPhone. Weird, I know.

That view will have subviews on top of it, or perhaps other `viewcontrollers`' views which want to respond appropriately to interface rotation. I basically want to lock a single view to portrait while letting my implementation of `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation` handle the rest.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe adding it as a subview of the main window will prevent it from being autorotated (because only UIViewControllers handle rotation).  Calling `[self.view.window addSubview:internalView];` should work perfectly. (though there are no guarantees as to what orientation the view is in when it is added).